# Issue with image reference outside function scope

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-canvas, yail

I have images being loaded with YAIL and it works perfectly but I need the "pill" image to be draggable and i need the pill image to be reference-able i've tried doing this by declaring pill as a variable outside the scope of the done() function but this does not work. I have so far:

```
var currentdate = new Date();
var datetime = currentdate.getHours();
var loader = new YAIL(done, progress, errors);
var pill = new Image();
if(datetime==1||datetime==13){
loader.add("clock/clock1.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==2||datetime==14){
loader.add("clock/clock2.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==3||datetime==15){
loader.add("clock/clock3.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==4||datetime==16){
loader.add("clock/clock4.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==5||datetime==17){
loader.add("clock/clock5.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==6||datetime==18){
loader.add("clock/clock6.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==7||datetime==19){
loader.add("clock/clock7.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==8||datetime==20){
loader.add("clock/clock8.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==9||datetime==21){
loader.add("clock/clock9.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==10||datetime==22){
loader.add("clock/clock10.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==11||datetime==23){
loader.add("clock/clock11.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==0||datetime==12){
loader.add("clock/clock12.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}


loader.load();
function done(e) { 
    var imageLst = e.images;
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(imageLst[0], 400, 180);
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(imageLst[1], 580, 350, 30,30);
    redpill=imageLst[1];

}
```

Comment: Your question title is misleading :{  YAIL would properly load your images--no problem there.  The actual problem: Canvas paints your images on the screen and then "forgets" them.  You can't reference your images or drag them--they are just "blobs of pixels on canvas".  Here's one tutorial on how to make canvas "remember" your images and let you drag them:  http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with YAIL but where you declare your variables.

You need to place the variable outside the function scope (as with any function) if you want to have access to it in other functions:

```
var imageLst;  /// declare here

function done(e) { 
    imageLst = e.images;  /// set here, images are now available outside done()

    canvas.ctx.drawImage(imageLst[0], 400, 180);
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(imageLst[1], 580, 350, 30,30);
    redpill=imageLst[1];
}
```

Note: `imageLst` will now be available to child functions. If you need to have access from any function you need to make sure `imageLst` is declared in global scope.

Note 2: even if the variable is available outside the function scope it is not actually set until done has completed. Therefor, as with any asynchronous operation, you will need to invoke the next step in your solution from within the done handler:

```
function done(e) {
    /// now the variable is set
    imageLst = e.images;

    /// go to next step in solution
    myNextStep();
}
```